# Efficient approximate algorithm to determine the presence of k-sized cycle in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have a very large sparse graph `G` (about 100 million nodes, about 50 million edges) and I would like to find an efficient algorithm (hopefully `O(1)` or sub-linear in the number of nodes + edges) that predicts with some probability the presence of a cycle of length `k` in this graph. For practical use, `k` will very small (between 30 and 90) relative to the size of `G`. It is also guaranteed that `k` will always be even. `G` is also a random graph, so I don't expect any consistent clustering.

The algorithm doesn't need to enumerate the actual nodes contained in the cycle, it just needs to eliminate `G` if it most likely don't have any cycles of length `k`.

I found a close solution with the answer presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/911040), where the `trace` and `rank` of `L` (where `L` is the Laplacian of `G`) could be compared to determine whether `G` had any cycles at all. However, I couldn't find a relatively efficient way to compute `rank` for `G`. Another problem was that it doesn't take `k` into account, which might be able to make a more efficient approach.

Getting connected components is a possibility, but it is linear in the number of nodes + edges, which is not optimal for a graph of this size.

Comment: Directed or undirected?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Both / either.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Erdos--Renyi random graph, then since having such a cycle is a monotone property of a graph, there's a zero-one law (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-10/S0002-9939-96-03732-X/S0002-9939-96-03732-X.pdf), which implies that you can make a reasonably good guess by setting the right threshold. (Which threshold? I don't know offhand, but probably you can extrapolate from smaller graphs.)